# Renaming single index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe where indexes are numeric subject IDs of respondents, who participated in sociological test.

Basically, the question is two-fold.

a). How can I rename single duplicate index in Pandas DataFrame?

A portion of data looks like this (first column is index):

```
subject build   gender_response
7   5.0.6.0 Female
5   5.0.6.0 Male
4   5.0.6.0 Male
3   5.0.6.0 Female
3   5.0.6.0 Female
1   5.0.6.0 Male
```

For example, I just need to reset one of the index ("3") to any other integer.

I have tried the major function from pandas documentation - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.rename.html However, if I set parameter "Inplace" to True, nothing happens:

```
master.iloc[3].rename(120, inplace=True)
```

If I create a new variable and use same expression without this parameter, it return a Pandas.Series with new index:( But I need it to be applied to new dataframe.

```
master2 = master.iloc[3].rename(120)
```

b). How to make changes conditional to a value in other columns?

```
  subject   time    Gender  Age
7   12:30:10    Female  23
5   12:23:10    Male    18
4   12:22:17    Male    36
3   12:16:55    Female  45
3   12:16:16    Female  67
1   12:05:22    Male    28
```

For example, I have column "time" the test have been taken on. I tried to do it via Pandas apply function, something like:

```
time_point = pd.Timestamp(1/19/2017 12:16:55)
def filter_by_time(x):
  if x[time] == Timestamp:
     x.index.rename(120)
```

Applied it to the rows of dataframe.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just noticed mistake in the last block of code.

Comment: time_point = pd.Timestamp(1/18/2017 12:16:55)
def filter_by_time(x):
  if x[time] == time_point:
     x.index.rename(120)

Comment: You should edit your question to fix the mistake.

Comment: Also, these are two different questions. Can you split your question, i.e. post two separate questions? That's how it works on SO.

Comment: Finally, can you confirm that `subject` is the index of your dataframe? It looks like it's just another column.

Comment: `rename` on an index assigns or changes the name attribute, it doesn't change the label, do the existing index labels matter? For instance you could just call `reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` if it doesn't

Comment: So, it does matter, because I have two datasets where one is demographic file and another is actual scores. Ultimately, I need to merge these two datasets and use subjectid as "common denominator"

Comment: So you want to keep this row or drop it? for instance you could call `reset_index()` and then `drop_duplicates(subset='subject')` if you want to remove it

Comment: I need it to be consistent with subject duplicates I have in two datasets.

Comment: What about the second part of the question? Making renaming conditional on a specific column value?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)? With `df.rename(index={1: 'a'}, inplace=True)` you can rename existing indices, although you won't be able to eliminate duplicates... I think this could help you with your second question?

Comment: Nope, it does not work. It changes two rows with indexes "3".

Comment: Sure, that's what it is supposed to do, I guess. If you want to avoid this, I would propose to introduce an additional column containing a "pure" index from 0..x. Then, you can still access the subject number, but you have a unique identifier for each row. The part which I don't get is your statement "I need it to be consistent with subject duplicates I have in two datasets". If you still need to identify, you can not just rename it arbitrarely, right? For me, the only way to keep the connection is to use an additional index-column?

Comment: @YevhenBarshchevskyi you can try this using index values, see answer

Comment: The answer posted by ErnestScribbler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427943/how-do-i-change-a-single-index-value-in-pandas-dataframe/49854311#49854311) may be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

**For Query 1,**

you are renaming a index on index location basis.So you can try this `master.index.values[3] = 120` instead `master.iloc[3].rename(120, inplace=True)`.

**For Query 2,** Try This

```
def filter_by_time(x):
    if x.name == "time":
        for index, value in enumerate(x):
            if value == pd.Timestamp("1/19/2017 12:16:55").strftime("%H:%M:%S"):
                master.index.values[index] = 120 
master.apply(filter_by_time)
```