# Pandas group and join

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I want to analysis the following case. Let say, A fruit market is giving the prices of the fruits daily the time from 18:00 to 22:00. For every half an hour they are updating the price of the fruits between the time lab. Consider the market giving the prices of the fruits at 18:00 as follows,

```
Fruit    Price
Apple     10
Banana    20
```

After half an hour at 18:30, the list has been updated as follows,

```
Fruit    Price
Apple     10
Banana    21
Orange    30
Grapes    25
Pineapple 65
```

I want to check has the prices of the fruits been changed of recent one[18:30] with the earlier one[18:00].
Here I want to get the result as,

```
Fruit   18:00   18:30
Banana    20     21
```

To solve this I am thinking to do the following,

```
1) Add time column in the two data frames.
2) Merge the tables into one.
3) Make a Pivot table with Index Fruit name and Column as ['Time','Price'].
```

I don't know how to get intersect the two data frames of grouped by Time. How to get the common rows of the two Data Frames.

Comment: Can you Create time and Update time. so that, you can get the value of Modified Fruit.

Comment: You don't need to pivot. Simply rename your price col for each dataframe as the proper time and do an "outer join" as argument in `pd.merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to pivot in this case, we can simply use `merge` and use `suffixes` argument to get the desired results:

```
df_update = pd.merge(df, df2, on='Fruit', how='outer', suffixes=['_1800h', '_1830h'])

    Fruit       Price_1800h Price_1830h
0   Apple       10.0        10.0
1   Banana      20.0        21.0
2   Orange      NaN         30.0
3   Grapes      NaN         25.0
4   Pineapple   NaN         65.0
```

**Edit**

Why are we using the `outer` argument? We want to keep all the new data that is updated in `df2`. If we use `inner` for example, we will not get the updated fruits, like below. Unless this is the desired output by OP, which is not clear in this case.

```
df_update = pd.merge(df, df2, on='Fruit', how='inner', suffixes=['_1800h', '_1830h'])

    Fruit   Price_1800h Price_1830h
0   Apple   10          10.0
1   Banana  20          21.0
```

Comment: That would not work in this case, since it would only give us back two rows (Apple, Banana) and not the updated other fruits. See my edit for explanation. @SergeBallesta

Comment: @Erfan: Thank you for the answer. I learned a new thing from your answer. But The suffix is needed only when the merged data frames have two columns with the same name. Am I right? What If I have extra column as 'Family of Fruit'. Will it work?

Comment: @SmithDwayne Family of Fruit would also be added indeed, since merge brings all the columns. Btw, you can accept an answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

If Fruit is the index of your data frame the following code should work. The Idea is to return rows with inequality:

```
df['1800'] = df1['Price']
df['1830'] = df2['Price']
print(df.loc[df['1800'] != df1['1830']])
```

---

You can also use [datetime in your column heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336863/pandas-datetimeindex-as-column-headings).

Comment: Some explanation of the code my also help learners. Code only answers are not always the most helpful. Please add some more text using the [edit] button.