# Panda add sum row with a string and integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For the Pandas dataframe

df

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines
C++            15             66       35                 354
C/C++ Header    1              3       7                   4
Markdown        6              73      0                  142
Python          110          1998     2086                4982
Tcl/Tk          1            14        18                 273
YAML            1             0         6                  20
```

when I use the code below, it sums each column with `NAN` for non-integer

```
df = df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

output

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines
C++            15             66       35                 354
C/C++ Header    1              3       7                   4
Markdown        6              73      0                  142
Python          110          1998     2086                4982
Tcl/Tk          1            14        18                 273
YAML            1             0         6                  20
NAN             134           2154     2152               5775
```

What should I change in the code to add a string "Total" instead of NAN

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines
C++            15             66       35                 354
C/C++ Header    1              3       7                   4
Markdown        6              73      0                  142
Python          110          1998     2086                4982
Tcl/Tk          1            14        18                 273
YAML            1             0         6                  20
TOTAL           134           2154     2152               5775
```

Comment: in Language Column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change a single index value in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427943/how-do-i-change-a-single-index-value-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

```
In [268]: total = df.sum()

In [269]: total['Language'] = 'Total'

In [270]: df.append(total, ignore_index=True)
Out[270]:
       Language  # of Files  Blank Lines  Comment Lines  Code Lines
0           C++          15           66             35         354
1  C/C++ Header           1            3              7           4
2      Markdown           6           73              0         142
3        Python         110         1998           2086        4982
4        Tcl/Tk           1           14             18         273
5          YAML           1            0              6          20
6         Total         134         2154           2152        5775
```

Comment: [`df.append` is deprecated since 1.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = np.insert('Total', 1, df.drop('Language', axis=1).sum(0))
```