# Barplot months against their cumulative values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make a bar plot of the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Months": [1, 2, 2, 4],
        "Value": ["1000", "2000", "1500", "3200"],
    }
)
```

The goal is to have a bar plot with `Months` on the `x-axis` and combined values from `Value` column on the `y-axis` (so in this case that would mean that only month 2 will be combined, essentially merging the rows where months are the same).

I also need to convert the numerical months to their text counterparts (so `1` becomes `January` etc.) and keep them in the correct  order on the x-axis (so January would be first, February second and so on).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should do the following:

1. Cast `Value` column to numerical type:

   ```
   df["Value"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Value"])
   ```
2. Group by months and sum `Value` columns for each month, lastly sorting by their numerical values (if you had `"Months": [1, 8, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1]` for example):

   ```
   df = df.groupby("Months", as_index=False).sum().sort_values("Months")
   ```
3. Months are sorted, so you can change their names (from `int` to `str` form):

   ```
   df["Months"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Months"], format="%m").dt.month_name()
   ```

   This operation would yield the following `pd.DataFrame`:

   ```
        Months  Value
   0   January   1000
   1  February   3500
   2     April   3200
   ```
4. Set index to `Months` (so it becomes x-axis of your plot) and use pandas plotting abilities.

   ```
   df.set_index("Months").plot.bar()
   ```

This operation yields following bar plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also help me with the following: I want to make the `Value` an average, so in that example the average `Value` of `February` would be devided by `2`. This needs to be shown in a bar plot as well. @Szymon Maszke

Comment: Can you explain why `as_index=False` is needed? And can it be done without? @Szymon Maszke

Comment: Otherwise `Months` column would become index of `DataFrame` and I wouldn't be able to modify it as column (cast numbers to months like `January` etc.). Step three would be harder to perform/less readable this way IMO and I'm not sure whether this approach could be used. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427943/how-do-i-change-a-single-index-value-in-pandas-dataframe) for modifying index, though this operation is more complicated and more pandas dependent.